# Making cookies on a pizza stone

Tags: baking, cookies, pizza-stone

Years and years ago, I had a pizza stone, and discovered that it was great for making thin and crispy cookies. That pizza stone cracked in half, and it was only this year that I bought another one. Can I make cookies on a pizza stone? Will all my cookies taste like pizza? Will my pizza taste like cookies?

Edit: My previous stone broke before I had made more than a few pizzas on it. I'm concerned that tastes might be retained by the stone over time; is this possible?

Comment: Why are you asking a question you answered in your first sentence?

Comment: Perhaps he only used the old one for cookies and hopes to use the new one for pizza as well as cookies? @Neil Fein please clarify.

Comment: I was reminded of this silly little question today, when I discovered: Don't bake cookies on an insulated cookie sheet on top of a pizza stone. (I had left the stone in the oven and forgotten to take it out, it basically lives on the bottom rack of my oven.) The cookies in the middle are significantly underdone, I suppose the stone sucks heat out of them--or maybe shunts heat to the perimeter? Not sure which.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Can I make cookies on a pizza stone?

Unless I'm misreading, you answered this yourself with your first sentence.

> Will all my cookies taste like pizza? Will my pizza taste like cookies?

Unless you're spilling pizza toppings onto the stone, no. Brushing it clean in between each usage will take care of any flavor transfer.

Comment: Good point, but my previous stone broke before I had made more than a few pizzas on it. I've since learned how to care for a pizza stone properly.

Answer (score 8):

As you discovered years ago, you can of course make cookies on your pizza stone.  If you are worried about taste, try putting parchment paper on top of your current stone under the cookies for a thin layer of separation.  I wouldn't worry about it, though.  What touches your stone from the pizza is the crust, and that's not usually a strong-tasting item.

Comment: I accepted hobodave's answer, but +1 here for the point about pizza crust being a fairly mild-tasting item. I may use parchment paper under cookies, to simply make it easier to clean up -- chocolate chips are fairly messy.

Comment: @Neil - I use parchment paper under my pizza (from the minute I roll out the crust).  It makes using the cookie sheet that is my pizza peel substitute significantly easier.  I can get a pizza in and out of the oven with no cornmeal or mess.